# asp .net Gridview change color of Vertical lines

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to change the color of the horizontal and the vertical lines of an asp .net gridview. I am changing the cell border color but only the horizontal lines are changed. You can see a picture attached.[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `RowDataBound`:

```
protected void gridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TableCell tc in e.Row.Cells)
    {
        tc.Attributes["style"] = "border-right:3px solid red; border-bottom:3px solid blue";
    }
}
```

Of course you can also use CSS classes(via `tc.CssClass`) instead of the inline css.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove all the borders and do followings,
Add following line of code in Grid View tag.

```
CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="1" Height="100%" GridLines="None" BackColor="#9CB6DB"
```

You will get the required result.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it by RowDataBound event, something like this:

```
protected void grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // check if it's a data row (not header and footer)
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // take a color from a condition or not... i don't know what is your case
        string color = condition ? "#ff9900" : "some-other-color";

        // set the color on X column, where X is your column index (starting by 0)
        e.Row.Cells[X].Attributes.Add("Style", "background-color: " + color + ";");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple to use properties of grid view as

```
<asp:GridView ID="grd_data" runat="server" 
     GridLines="Both" CssClass="gridline"></asp:GridView>
```

You can also use specific horizontal and vertical

Create a css in style sheet as external file or inline

```
.gridline tr, .gridline td, .gridline th
{
    border-top: 1px solid  #DDDDDD;
    border-bottom: 1px solid  #DDDDDD;
    border-left:1px solid  #DDDDDD;
    border-right:1px solid  #DDDDDD;
}
```